# Checking the criterion for the positive definiteness of a matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

The article [Bounds for Elgenvalues Using Traces](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/reports/bndseigs80.pdf) on page 482 has the following statement:

> If  $A$  is Hermitian,  the  inequality  (2.36)  shows that  $A$  is positive  definite when $$\frac{\mbox{Tr}(A)^2}{\mbox{Tr}(A^2)} > n-1$$

---

Here is an example of a symmetric positive-definite Hermitian matrix of the 4th order, for which the indicated criteria are not met. **Why?**

**Remarque:** It is not entirely clear from the article what the parameter $f$ is, but this formula even got into [Definite Matrix - Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Properties). I ask the help of experts in trying to figure it out and I will be grateful.

```
n=4

A = {{4, 10, 30, 100}, {10, 30, 100, 354}, {30, 100, 354, 1300}, {100, 354, 1300, 4890}};

HermitianMatrixQ[A];

Eigenvalues[A] // N;

Tr[A] && Tr[A]^2/Tr[MatrixPower[A, 2]] > n - 1;
```

Comment: The statement you quoted from the paper merely says that *if* the condition is satisfied, *then* $\ A\ $ is positive definite.  It does *not* say that the condition will always be satisfied whenever $\ A\ $ is positive definite.

Comment: Wasn't there a "and $\mbox{tr} (A)$" there also?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It was, I just make the elements on the diagonal positive in advance, so this condition is automatically fulfilled, although I introduced it into the calculation in Mathematica for the future.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Clearly, this is a type of inequality. And can you tell me if there are any other inequalities (including simple ones) that can be used like criteria to judge positive definiteness? Just not the Sylvester criterion and its hard modifications, please!

Comment: @lonzaleggiera And by the way, I want to note that in the case of the 4th order of the matrix and higher, in principle, it is impossible to satisfy this inequality.

Comment: @dtn I don't know any other simple and easily testable set of inequalities for guaranteeing that a matrix is positive definite, but it's not true that the inequality $\ \frac{\text{Tr}(A)^2}{\text{Tr}(A^2)}>n-1\ $ is impossible to satisfy for $\ n\ge4\ $. If the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $ all lie within an interval $\ [m,M]\ $, for instance, where $\ 0\le m\le M<\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}\ $ then
$$
\frac{\text{Tr}(A)^2}{\text{Tr}(A^2)}\ge \frac{(nm)^2}{nM^2}>n-1\ .
$$

Comment: Even when these conditions are very far from being satisfied, however, it's still possible for the inequality to hold.  If $\ A\ $ is a $\ 4\times4\ $ matrix with eigenvalues $\ 1,2,3,4\ $, for instance, then $\ \frac{\text{Tr}(A)^2}{\text{Tr}(A^2)}=\frac{100}{30}>4-1\ $.

Comment: The quantity $\ f\ $ is defined in the statement of corollary $2.2$ on p.$480$.  It's the number of positive eigenvalues of $\ A\ $.